# Error print user.default swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have two screens the first of login and the second shows the user information. On the login screen I keep the user_id value in user.defaults and when I go to the second screen I use that value to call a web service and show its information, but I have an error and that the value saved in user.default is nil. and finally when user click cerrar_sesion I remove the user.defaults How can I solve it? This is my code:

```
func login(){
        let id_usuario = 7
        Constants.lbd.set(id_usuario, forKey: "id_usuario")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second_view", sender: self)
        Constants.lbd.synchronize()
}
```

Second view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btn_cerrarSesion.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cerar_sesion), for: .touchUpInside)
        info_usuario()
}

    func info_usuario(){
            let auth = "ASASDWDASD!"
            let id_usuario = Constants.lbd.object(forKey: "id_usuario") as? Int
print(id_usuario)
            Services.objServices.ServObtUsuario(auth: auth!, id_usuario: id_usuario!).then{
                data -> Void in
                let res = JSON(data)
                let status = res["status"].boolValue
                if(status){
                    let info_usuario = res["data"]["usuarios"]
                    for(_, sub_res):(String, JSON) in info_usuario{
                        self.lbl_nombres_usuario.text = sub_res["nombres"].stringValue+" "+sub_res["apellidos"].stringValue
                        self.lbl_username.text = sub_res["username"].stringValue
                    }
                }else{
                    let error = res["error"]["error_data"].stringValue
                    print(error)
                }
                }.catch{
                    error -> Void in
            }
        }


func cerar_sesion(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second_view", sender: self)
        Constants.lbd.object(forKey: "id_usuario")        
        Constants.lbd.removeObject(forKey: "id_empresa")
        Constants.lbd.removeObject(forKey: "rol")
        Constants.lbd.removeObject(forKey: "auth")
        Constants.lbd.synchronize()
    }
```

finally I get this in console: 
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try calling synchronize before calling perform segue `
Constants.lbd.synchronize()
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second_view", sender: self)`

Comment: @Diego Israel Moreno You need to call synchronize () after saving data.

Comment: What value you are getting in print(id_usuario)

Comment: @SucharuHasija nil my friend

Comment: here is the problem, You are not getting the value from your constants

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno: I have added my answer. Please check

Comment: @SandeepBhandari No, you do not need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: @TusharSharma No, you do not need to call `synchronize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

For your line of code:

```
Constants.lbd.set(id_usuario, forKey: "id_usuario")
```

User this:

```
   UserDefaults.standard.set(id_usuario,forKey:"id_usuario") // Use Integer to store this value
```

For your line of code in Second VC:

```
 let id_usuario = Constants.lbd.object(forKey: "id_usuario") as? Int
```

User this:

```
  let id_usuario =   UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey:"id_usuario") // Use Integer to store this value
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: I do that but I get the value = 0

Comment: I get the value 0 when I remove Constants.lbd.removeObject(forKey: "id_usuario")

Comment: please replace the both lines

Comment: Yes i do I get the value 0 when I install by first time the app, after that I can get the value of id_usuario

Comment: I can solve the problem But your answer IS CORRECT thanks my friend

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is a dedicated method to read an `Int` from `UserDefaults` (assuming `Constants.lbd` is a *type alias* for `UserDefaults.standard`)

```
let id_usuario = Constants.lbd.integer(forKey: "id_usuario")
```

Second of all don't use `UserDefaults` to share data between view controllers. It's fine to save the value in `UserDefaults` but it's better to pass the value in the segue for example via the `sender` parameter

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second_view", sender: id_usuario)
```

---

And please, this is Swift and not PHP or JavaScript. The variable and function names are supposed to be *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*.

Comment: "The variable and function names are supposed to be camelCased rather than snake_cased." hahahahaha :) Nice answer hence +1 :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to call `synchronize` method of `Userdefaults` immediately after saving the value.

By default, user default will take some time to save the new value into `Plist`.

The only disadvantage of calling synchronizes method of `Userdefaults` is it will take process time.

Additionally, avoid forced unwrapping.

Comment: Yes I use synchronize I forgot, but I get the same error

Comment: According to Apple documentation: "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize